# Animating intersecting objects

Tags: animation

I would like to animate two intersecting objects, for example, a fixed sphere and a moving plane. How can I animate their motion so that when they intersect, their (changing) intersection appears as a separate object (so can be assigned a different color)?

Comment: I guess you could use booleans: a boolean to reveal an object (the addition of your 2 objects), and another one to hide another

Comment: could you please provide a drawing of what you would like exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to have two intersecting 3d objects ( such as solidified sphere and plane). I know how to do this using Boolean for static frames. But what if the objects are in motion? Can the Booleans operate when the objects are in motion and being animated?

Comment: sure, you can animate the boolean object, you can parent it to the booleaned object, move it, etc...